# Django comments security_hash

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-comments

Getting an error with a HiddenInput field called "security_hash"

It says in the [documentation](http://django-contrib-comments.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html?highlight=security_hash#notes-on-the-comment-form) that had I used {{ form }} in my template these values would have been created automatically

But I am not using a template, rather just the comments/post/ endpoint with POST data as follows:

[image]

How can I get the security_hash value without this extra view to pass in as POST value?

Edit: I am thinking would it be possible and advisable to pass the {{ form.security_hash }} value from the template/view to the form behind the scenes so this error can be averted.

Edit2: For clarification the security_hash field in question is [shown here in code](https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/django_comments/forms.py#L25,73) the security_hash value looks like it is being generated from the 'initial_security_hash' function which uses the `content_type, object_pk`, and `timestamp` fields to generate a hash on line 73, this function is called on line 69.

Due to this I am also further confused as to why my input is not being accepted as I pass in the `content_type, object_pk`, and `timestamp` fields

Comment: Can you give more details about your actual calling context? Where are you initiating the POST request? I’m guessing you are not actually using the provided `CommentSecurityForm`. What is your actual context?

Comment: @metahamza I am making a call at the /post/ endpoint as specfied in the urls.py file (https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/django_comments/urls.py#L11) which links to this view (https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/django_comments/views/comments.py#L34). I am providing all the details as shown in the picture in my question with my POST call.

Comment: Yes that makes sense, I meant more like, where does the POST call initiate from? From an AJAX call in JavaScript? From a worker process? Another Django view?

Comment: If my answer works for you, please mark it as such! Thanks :)

Comment: @metahamza sorry about the delay was on a bit of a break, my context btw was an iOS app using a REST POST call.

Comment: I tried your ans out but `CommentSecurityForm(users.MyUser)` cannot be instantiated in this way as i get `_get_pk_val() missing argument:'self`, I could not figure the exact way to do so for my use case. I think a custom class which inherits from CommentSecurityForm and in the create method generate_security_data could work.But I don't think this hash is providing me much security (just ensures that the target object for the comment is not changed). Thus I think it is best for my case to patch this security check away.Your ans provides the right direction tho, ill add relevant comments later.

Comment: Ok, makes sense! Yeah its a bit tricky, it seems that the comments framework originally intended for you to build this form via a provided template tag which is a bit of a black box. Glad my answer helped point a direction. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the security hash is generated from an instantiated `CommentSecurityForm`. Then the security hash value is included as a hidden field and passed back through the POST request, at which time it is validated.

Even though you are passing the `content_type`, `object_pk`, and `timestamp` fields to the request, it doesn’t matter because you need to have the `security_hash` value *before* the POST request is submitted.

Look at the doc here - https://github.com/django/django-contrib-comments/blob/master/django_comments/forms.py#L62

I’m guessing you are not using the provided `CommentSecurityForm`, which would include the security validation fields automatically.

If that assumption is correct, you should instantiate the form, something like

```
my_form = CommentSecurityForm(users.MyUser)
security_dict = my_form.generate_security_data()
```

Then, this `security_dict` containers the following keys - `content_type`, `object_pk`, `timestamp`, `security_hash`. You’ll then need to pass these values to whatever context your POST request initiates from and include them in the request for the security validation to pass.

Comment: You passed the `MyUser` model without instantiating it to the `CommentSecurityForm` is that intentional?